# Noise cancelling software for work on linux

Tags: linux

I'm looking for a noise canceling software for Linux that works with or without music. My headphone is simple, doesn't has noise canceling.
There are some recommendations?

Best regards.
Willian

Answer (score 1):

You can enable noise cancellation in Ubuntu without any extra software or hardware. You can do it with the help of Ubuntu’s default pulse software. You need to import noise/echo cancellation module in defaults file of pulse and restart your machine to see changes. Please check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1U_qdEtNwhE&t=73s) for video tutorial or you can read my [article](https://medium.com/@rahul.y.dudhane/how-to-do-noise-and-echo-cancellation-in-ubuntu-7a5607c7e887) on this. Please follow the given links. Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

I found multiple answers with search this keyword:

> "noise canceling in Linux "

I suggest seeing this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18958/realtime-noise-removal-with-pulseaudio) and this another [link](https://somtips.com/remove-background-noise-of-microphone-on-linux-system/) and if you have a problem ask it again.

## from the link one:

Pulseaudio module-echo-cancel could be what you want. 
after install Pulseaudio in your machine:

1. sudo nano /etc/pulse/default.pa
2. Add the following line anywhere on the file, but I recommend almost at the end where you will find a comment about Echo Cancellation stuff (~line 140):

   load-module module-echo-cancel
3. Reload PulseAudio (`[pulseaudio -k][3]`) or simply restart the computer. You should be able to select the new Noise Cancellation option from the Input Device Section:

[image: screenshot]

You can find more information about it on the [Echo Cancel Module Page](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index45h3)

### Set input as default

If you wish to [set as default](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Set_default_input_sources) the echo cancel device simply turn the above line into:

```
load-module module-echo-cancel source_name=logitechsource
```

and then at the bottom of the file add

```
set-default-source logitechsource
```

In this case, I named the source `logitechsource`, but you can name it whatever you want and simply either restart pulseaudio.

### Rename device

Lastly, if you do not want a super long name on the Sound Settings (When you want to select an input/output device). My suggestion is renaming the input device like this:

```
load-module module-echo-cancel source_name=logitechsource source_properties=device.description=LogitechHD
```

And again, restarting pulseaudio. The end result looks like this:

[image: screenshot]